# Open Graph Tutorial assumptions? and misunderstandings? resulting in "Error Occured"?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

It is important to note that i have never created a Facebook App before and have no idea where to start - the assumption being that answers would be given in the open graph step-by-step tutorial.

I got as far as Step 4 and get the now famous "error occurred" dialog - It could be due to one or more misunderstandings and problems with the code examples. Id appreciate some clarity as certain "assumptions" may be the root of all my problems

To save time I jumped to the end of the tutorial and downloaded the example code and have used that for my final code (object.html)

1. App Domain and Site URL - your tutorial says to choose the website option  - i used the following for app domain:

www.teamworks.co.za and for site url: www.teamworks.co.za/grow/object.html

this means i can access the page independently of facebook, whether im logged in or not

Question :is this the intention or was it supposed to run inside of facebook? (i.e. have I missed something here?)
Question: will the page pick up my user credentials from my facebook login? (when i have facebook open and logged in on same browser - but different tab)
Question: How do my test users launch the app - when logged in as a test user i see the app - it has a settings page but no click-able link to open the page?

1. Images: there is no explicit instruction to change the location of the images in sample code here:`<meta property="og:image"  content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" />`

or here:

```
<img title="Stuffed Cookies" src="http://fbwerks.com:8000/zhen/cookie.jpg" width="550"/>
```

except in the final downloadable code example which indicates:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://YOUR_URL/cookie.jpg" />
```

and

```
<img title="Oreo Stuffed Cookies" src="http://YOUR_URL/cookie.jpg" width="550"/><br />
```

When i use the the supplied image locations i get errors when i debug, for example:

Tiny og:image:  All the images referenced by og:image must be at least 200px in both dimensions. Please check all the images with tag og:image in the given url and ensure that it meets the minimum specification.

The debugger does not complain when i use my own image location i.e. mydomain/grow/cookie.jpg (for both images)

Question: Can i therefore safely assume that i can replace the image url's with my own and it is not the cause of the "error occurred" dialog?

1. The download example has an extra bit of code i.e 
   `<fb:add-to-timeline></fb:add-to-timeline>`>
   note the double >> at the end - i deleted this out for now as it is not covered in the tutorial 
   Question: can i safely assume that deleting is not the cause of the "error occurred" dialog?
2. The downloaded example  tag:
   `<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# og_recipebox: http://ogp.me/ns/apps/YOUR_NAMESPACE#">`
   which translates to:
   `<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# og_recipebox: http://ogp.me/ns/apps/groworganic#">`
   looks different to the one that is generated when clicking on the recepie object "get code" button i.e.
   `<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# groworganic: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/groworganic#">`
   Question: Which is the correct  to use?

5.The downloaded example has this script tag

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

which i assume replaces the following code from the tutorial:

```
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));
```

Question: is this assumption correct?

I'm am no longer getting an error but also i am not getting success either - i am getting no response now- however the code passes the debug test.

i will have to start again, in the meantime i copied my code below in the hopes that i will get some answers to my questions above.

below is the code for my object.html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"> 
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# og_recipebox: http://ogp.me/ns/apps/groworganic#"> 
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="472670852757244" /> 
<meta property="og:type" content="groworganic:recepie" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Oreo Stuffed Cookies" /> 
<meta property="og:image"  content="http://www.teamworks.co.za/grow/cookie.jpg" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="The Turducken of Cookies" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.teamworks.co.za/grow/object.html"> <script type="text/javascript">
function postCook()
{
FB.api(
'/me/groworganic:cook',
'post',
{ recipe: 'http://www.teamworks.co.za/grow/object.html' },
function(response) {
if (!response) {
alert('Error occurred : No Response');
} else if (response.error) {
alert('Error occurred : ' + response.error);
} else {
alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
}
});
}
</script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({ 
appId:'472670852757244', cookie:true, 
status:true, xfbml:true, oauth:true
});
</script>
<h3>
<font size="30" face="verdana" color="grey">Stuffed Cookies
</font> 
</h3> 
<p>
<img title="Oreo Stuffed Cookies" src="http://www.teamworks.co.za/grow/cookie.jpg" width="550"/><br />
</p>       
<form>
<input type="button" value="Cook" onclick="postCook()" />
</form>
<fb:activity actions="groworganic:cook"></fb:activity>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Agreed with CBroe *way too many questions* in here. Please break it up into separate posts to make it easier for users to tackle the problems individually. Also `To save time I jumped to the end of the tutorial and downloaded the example code and have used that for my final code` you shouldn't do that >.< (unless you have prior experience) if you are trying to learn the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

> Question: will the page pick up my user credentials from my facebook login?

No, you’ll have to log the user in (have them “connect” to your app) yourself first. You can use `FB.login` out of the JS SDK for that.

For the rest of your posting: **Too many questions at once.**

> It is important to note that i have never created a Facebook App before

Then you should probably not start with publishing Open Graph actions straight away, but deepen your knowledge about how user authentication and interacting with the Graph API works first. Do some simple stuff, where the user can log in and gets his personal info from the Graph API shown or something … once you understand those basic, you can move along to more complex topics such as Open Graph actions.